# for loop output formatting: add newline with a description and space

Tags: bash, loops, formatting

I'm running through a list of files to cat and redirecting all of the output to a single file using a for loop. My loop works but i'm looking for a way to add a descriptor line before each file's contents is dumped and add a space before each new file entry. Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(ls -l /home/user/*.txt | awk 'NR>=2 {print $9}')

for i in $files; do /bin/cat "$i" >> "/home/user/catfiles.txt"
done
```

My output looks like this:

```
 spawn ssh user@x.x.x.x
 run $command
 quit
 spawn ssh user@x.x.x.x
 run $command
 quit
```

I would like for it to look like this:

```
 "Description for first file here"
 spawn ssh user@x.x.x.x
 run $command
 quit
 <space>
 "Description for second file here"
 spawn ssh user@x.x.x.x
 run $command
 quit
 <space>
```

UPDATE: The file description name would need to vary by file using the actual file name.

```
"This is $file1"
"This is $file2"
 etc,etc..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will merge them as you require it:

```
for f in /home/user/*.txt;do
    echo "This is ${f##*/}" >> /home/user/catfiles.txt
    /bin/cat "${f}" >> /home/user/catfiles.txt
    echo >> /home/user/catfiles.txt
done
```

The file name is printed **without** its path. If you want the path printed, too, then simply replace `${f##*/}` with `${f}`.

**Update**

`${variable##pattern}` is called parameter substitution. Bash will search for `pattern` in `variable` and remove the longest match. In this case the variable is `f` and pattern is `*/` which matches any String that ends with a slash. The double hash `##` indicates to remove the longest String in `f` that can be matched by `*/`. Since `f` is a path it will match and remove everything up to and including the last `/`, thus leaving only the filename.
The [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) has further and more detailed info on this subject. Alternatively, you can search in `man bash` for `Parameter Expansion`.

Comment: Can you explain how the "##*/" removes the file path?

Answer (score 1):

So you want this, and BTW your `files=$(ls -l /home/user/*.txt | awk 'NR>=2 {print $9}')` is wrong, [don't parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) output, jus use shell:

```
for i in /home/user/*.txt; do
    echo "Description for first file here $i" >> /home/user/catfiles.txt
    /bin/cat "$i" >> "/home/user/catfiles.txt"
    echo >> /home/user/catfiles.txt
done
```

Comment: No but close, maybe I was not clear enough. The description would need to vary, and take on some defining characteristic of "file 1", "file 2", etc..Such as the actual file name. So for example we would echo "This is $file1", This is $file2, etc..

Comment: @user53029 so use $i in the description part, as shown above

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve the issue:

```
for i in /home/user/*; do
echo "This is from $i" >> "/home/user/catfiles.txt"
/bin/cat "$i" >> "/home/user/catfiles.txt"
    echo >> "/home/user/catfiles.txt"
done
```

Since "i" represents each file in this case, $i in the second line starting with echo will give you the different filename.

If you want to exclude the file path so the line simply has the file name without the /home/user you can insert a sed statement after the 3rd line.

```
for i in /home/user/*; do
echo "This is from $i" >> "/home/user/catfiles.txt"
/bin/cat "$i" >> "/home/user/catfiles.txt"
/bin/sed -i -e 's/\/home\/user\///g' /home/user/catfiles.txt
    echo >> "/home/user/catfiles.txt"
done
```

Comment: There is no need to run an additional `sed` if you want to exclude the path. Bash can do this via parameter substitution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.